# Routes with /"model" bypassing routes defined in routes.js

Tags: security, routes, request, sails.js

Well, i'm building a back-end project on Sails.js in the default port 1337, and everytime i send a get request like "localhost:1337/user", while user is a model, the server responds with all the content in that table. I have a controller for that model, but this request bypass the entire controller and sends all user informations in the table.
I already tried overwriting the '/user' request with a function that sends nothing in response, but still sending every information in the table.
Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Do you have blueprints enabled ? 
 https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints/blueprint-routes#?restful-blueprint-routes

Comment: yes they are enabled, you think thats the problem?

Comment: Most likely, if you want to keep blueprints enabled you'll have to make a route for /user where you return a 404 or so. I've never used them but I don't think sails recommends you to have blueprints enabled in production anyway.

Comment: Oh ok, fair enough. i`ll disable blueprints, but my temporary solution was to use the action:forbidden in the blueprint routes.